# Clamp meter and APC PDU amperage reading in disagreement by 3A -- how is this possible?

Tags: clamp

I have a cabinet of servers in a datacenter. The cabinet is powered by a 208V 30A 2-pole circuit with a L6-30R outlet. I plug my APC AP8941 power distribution unit into that outlet. I follow the 80% rule and I keep my power load below 24A -- as indicated by the amperage reading on the LCD display of my APC AP8941. My current power usage (as indicated by the APC PDU) is ~22.7A

I was recently contacted by the datacenter staff that my circuit was running hot at the panel and my circuit was drawing power above the 80% rule -- they sent me a photo of their electrician using a Klein clamp meter indicating 25.8 amps. They also showed me a photo of a crispy looking wire and said it belong to my circuit.

The datacenter is essentially blaming me for this problem -- stating that I need to get under 24A as soon as possible.

Figuring that my APC PDU might be displaying an incorrect reading, I swapped it out with my backup AP8941 PDU. However, the power reading was still ~22.7A.

So my questions are:

- How is it possible for there to be a 3A difference in the amperage reading done by the clamp meter at the panel and from my APC PDU in the server cabinet?
- Could the excess heat at the panel (perhaps caused by loose connections, electrical resistance) cause an elevated clamp meter reading?
- If the circuit was installed properly, should it be possible to have this level of heat damage?

[image: clamp meter]

[image: crispy wire]

Comment: Is that really a green wire they're measuring on?  If so, question everything.  Also, yes a poor breaker connection can result in elevated temps.  Miss-matched measurements do indicate a shadow circuit somewhere that isn't being included.  Look for an extension cord running out the window ;~)

Comment: Does your 208V circuit also have a neutral (L6-30R implies that no, you do not - and that's fine)?  If so, perhaps you have unbalanced (120V) loads on the circuit, causing the confusion?

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Hard to say, but the left side of the wire looks green to me and the right side looks... blue? Maybe heat damage caused the color change? :shrugs: I'm not sure about the presence of a neutral wire, but I can ask.

Comment: "If the circuit was installed properly, should it be possible to have this level of heat damage?"  The fact that humans are involved means that this can, and does happen.  The fact that the damage is near the breaker terminal strongly incriminates the connection at the breaker - as long as the rest of the circuit checks out.

Comment: red wire #22 looks like it is directly under the screw head ... is there a clamp plate that it should be under? ... #18 and #20 look like they are on the wrong side of the screw ... #18 looks like it is only partially clamped ... please add closeup photos of the wire connections